# reading large csv file contain comma with php

Tags: php, csv

i have csv file that i need to read with php.I used 2 method but there is problem in theme.

methode i used are:
1- file_get_contents
2-fgetcsv
let explaine about csv file. the problem about the file is the fields contain comma that is used for delimiter and its bothering.
the first methode is fast but commas in the fiels make it work incorrectly like number seperator 14,200 . i fixed it withe a function named fixed number. but there is still random text that contain comma and doesnt follow any rule that i can fix them
the second method for large csv is very slow and i cant get out put to see that its working
the code for first methode is like:

```
$myFile = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\r\n",$myFile);//file to an array


while($counter <= count($lines)){
$data=$lines[$counter]; 

$tmp=fixnumbers($data);
$tmp=eregi_replace('"', '',$tmp);
$tmp=explode(',',$tmp); 


if(count($tmp)> 0 ){
$newdata[$datacounter]=$tmp;//explode('*0*',$data);
$datacounter++;
}
$counter++;
}
```

the second methode is here :

```
$handle= fopen($file,"r");
    $row=1;
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $num = count($data);

      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $mydata[$row][$c]=$data[$c] . "<br />\n";
      }$row++;
   }

print "<div class=\"longList\"><pre>";  
        print_r($mydata);
print "</pre></div>";
    fclose($file);


}
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your csv file?  If a numeric field has a comma in it, then it should be a text field instead and quoted, which `fgetcsv` should handle properly.

Comment: here is a sample file but its not english :  https://rapidgator.net/file/ef4f99844b702a8fa3871cc7acaee4af/خاموشیهای_ف_م_استان-با_برنامه.csv.html

Comment: ang fgetcsv is very slower than file_get_content in my experience

Comment: The few lines I looked at it seemed like the quotes were properly applied.  `fgetcsv` should be able to deal with that for you.

Comment: i run the second code with fgetcsv and use this file. but it takes more than 10 min and still no out put or max php execution time error

Comment: I have found this example in the manual to be pretty reliable `$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));` from the comments in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: thanks alot  array_map('str_getcsv', file($file)); works fine. i will test it on other csv if there is problem. it takes me a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I waited the minute to download the file, grabbed the first 5 records, and used a copy/paste of the `fgetcsv` example in the PHP manual.

First 5 records - https://termbin.com/23ti - saved as "sm_file.csv"

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen("sm_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $data=array();
    $num=0;
    while (($data[] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print_r($data);
}

?>



[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => از تاريخ وصل 01/07/1397 - با برنامه
        [1] => تاريخ گزارش: 29/09/1397
        [2] => شماره گزارش: (3-5)
        [3] => صفحه 1
        [4] => گزارش قطع و وصل فيدرهاي فشار متوسط (نمونه 3)
        [5] => ملاحظات
        [6] => شرايط جوي
        [7] => عملكرد ريكلوزر
        [8] => رله عامل
        [9] => خاموشي (MWh)
        [10] => بار فيدر (A)
        [11] => مدت قطع
        [12] => زمان وصل
        [13] => تاريخ وصل
        [14] => زمان قطع
        [15] => تاريخ قطع
        [16] => نوع اشكال بوجود آمده
        [17] => فيدر فشار متوسط
        [18] => پست فوق توزيع
        [19] => شماره پرونده
        [20] => رديف
        [21] =>  ناحيه اسالم
        [22] => 
        [23] => آفتابي
        [24] => ندارد
        [25] => ندارد
        [26] => 0.21
        [27] => 3
        [28] => 132
        [29] => 11:30
        [30] => 1397/07/04
        [31] => 09:18
        [32] => 1397/07/04
        [33] => جهت كار در حريم شبكه
        [34] => گيسوم
        [35] => اسا لم
        [36] => 96,042,429,972
        [37] => 1
        [38] => 61292.56
        [39] => جمع کل بار فيدر:
        [40] => 393.85
        [41] => جمع کل خاموشي:
        [42] => 92,725
        [43] => جمع مدت قطع:
    )
```

Looks like data element 36 is the one you are having issues with, as you can see `fgetcsv` handles it fine, you just need to convert from a string to a number as you process the data.  Just strip the commas.

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen("sm_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $data=array();
    $num=0;
    while (($data[] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[(count($data)-1)][36]=str_replace(",","",$data[(count($data)-1)][36]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print_r($data);
}

?>
```

Which gives

```
[36] => 96042429972
```

As for how long it takes, your full file of 2k records

```
User time (seconds): 0.12
System time (seconds): 0.09
Percent of CPU this job got: 43%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.52
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 41820
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2448
Voluntary context switches: 18
Involuntary context switches: 55
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

on a modest i5 w/ 8gb ram.  Not seeing any issues.

Comment: thanks for reply. i solved the numbers with comma problem but there is some text with comma that i can not handle with file_get_content methode. also i dont know why fgetcsv take too long for me to get output. last time i use $array = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));. it seems working fine but i need to test it on many csv for sure. anyway thank you again

Comment: i modified the script and run the script with about 1500 record plus inserting into mysql database. it taking about 2 min. im worried about csv with more than 10000 record. my laptop is i5 and 4gb memory. i increase php memory limit to 512 mb. can u suggest a way to decrease the run time or doit seperately without split csv manualy."my work pc that i want to run this script is dual core" but the run time is like my laptop. i think its not to do with cpu very much. but i dont know how to increase the running and inserting to database speed

Comment: if i print the output it even take longer time